# Access Windows Registry inside R

Tags: r, registry

How can I access the windows registry inside R. For example, I want to access the folder:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\R-core\R\3.0.2]
```

and the key called "InstallPath"

to get:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.0.2"
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you really want: to be able to access the registry or to be able to get the path to the R executable? If you just want the path to the R executable, what do you plan to do with that?

Comment: Also note that one can install R without installing a registry entry so you can't be 100% sure that that registry entry exists.

Comment: The R path was just an example. I want to be able to get a configuration key of which idiom is currently being used in a program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `readRegistry()`.

On my machine:

```
fp <- file.path("SOFTWARE", "R-core", "R", "3.1.0", fsep="\\")
readRegistry(fp, "HLM")  ## "HLM" eventually resolves to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
# $InstallPath
# [1] "C:\\R\\R-current"
```

(Also, for future reference, in this case you could probably have found that out with a quick call to `apropos("registry")` or even `apropos("reg")`.)

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not obvious why you'd need to access the registry. If you just want the home directory of your R installation, you can use `R.home()`. Alternatively you could use `Sys.getenv("R_HOME")`. If that doesn't give you what you need (I can't test on Windows right now), maybe one of the other environment variables gives you what you need.